# r function in function arguments + apply

Tags: r, function, arguments, apply

I'm having troubles using several functions within the same one and calling the arguments generated. I'm using a more complicated function that can be simplified as followed:

```
 func.essai <- function(x) {
 g <- sample(seq(1,30), x)
 i <- sample(x,1)
 func.essai.2 <- function(y,i) {
  z <- y+i
 }
 h <- sapply(g,func.essai.2(y,i))
}
sq <- seq(1,4)
lapply(sq, func.essai)
```

I'm using arguments that are generated at the beginning of `func.essai` (and that depend on `x`) as a fixed input for `func.essai.2`, here for `i`, and as a vector to go through on the `sapply` function, here for `g`. This code doesn't work as such -- it doesn't recognize `y` and/or `i`. How can I rewrite the code to do so?

Comment: What is the expected output? And the variable y is not defined anywhere, is it?

Comment: A list of the z generated (=y+i) for each value of sq, and each value of g

Comment: Second argument of sapply must be a function, by adding the parameter `(y,i)` you're passing the result of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error you get is because of your use of sapply. This should work instead of your line containing `sapply`:

```
 h <- sapply(g,func.essai.2, i)
```

See `?sapply`, which tells you that you should provide additional arguments behind the function that you are applying.

Comment: An alternative would be to use an anonymous function: `sapply(g, function(x) func.essai.2(x, i))`